# Cant give color background on React Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Hello guys so I'm trying to make app using react-bootstrap and now I'm trying to make the footer, but I cant give **background color** to my footer using `*` tag. It will give **background color** to all of my components, not only my footer component. Can anyone help me with it ? appreciate any help.

My code:

```
import '../styles/Footer.css'
import {Row, Col} from "react-bootstrap"

const Footer = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Row>
                <Col md={12} lg={4} className= "footerleft">
                    <img alt="Logo  Hotel"></img>
                </Col>

                <Col md={12} lg={4} className= "footermid">
                    <h3>Contact Info</h3>
                    <hr></hr>

                    <p>Email:
                    </p>
                </Col>

                <Col md={12} lg={4} className= "footerright">
                    <h3> Follow Us</h3>
                    <hr></hr>

                    <a><img src="" alt="Facebook Logo"></img></a>
                    <a><img src="" alt="Instagram Logo"></img></a>
                </Col>
            </Row>

            <div className="copyright">
                <hr></hr>
                <p>
                    Copyright © 2014
                    <br/>
                    All Rights Reserved
                </p>
            </div>

        </>
    )
}

export default Footer
```

My Footer.css:

```
*{
    background-color: blue;
}
.copyright{
    text-align: center;
}

.copyright hr{
    color: #967A50;
}
```

Comment: * selector affects on all elements, you should set a unique class name for footer container.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like following, add a class and give that class the color.

```
return (
    <div className="footer">
        <Row>
            <Col md={12} lg={4} className= "footerleft">
                <img alt="Logo  Hotel"></img>
            </Col>

            <Col md={12} lg={4} className= "footermid">
                <h3>Contact Info</h3>
                <hr></hr>

                <p>Email:
                </p>
            </Col>

            <Col md={12} lg={4} className= "footerright">
                <h3> Follow Us</h3>
                <hr></hr>

                <a><img src="" alt="Facebook Logo"></img></a>
                <a><img src="" alt="Instagram Logo"></img></a>
            </Col>
        </Row>

        <div className="copyright">
            <hr></hr>
            <p>
                Copyright © 2014
                <br/>
                All Rights Reserved
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
)
```

And in css replace this

```
* {
    background-color: blue;
  }
```

with this

```
 .footer {
   background-color: blue;
 }
```